# Jquery, scrollTop == overscrolled?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I want to start an event when my `$(window).scrollTop == 500`. If I scroll slow it works, but if I scroll fast nothing happens. Do you have any ideas how to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen as the `scroll` event fires for every pixel that an element is scrolled by. This could potentially mean an event handler gets fired hundreds of times in under a second, so the browser will 'skip' some of those events based on the tick rate of the UI thread.

This means that it may only detect certain scrollTop values when scrolling, so `scrollTop` may only be read at `480`, `499`, `522`, given your code sample. Therefore your test of `== 500` would not hit, even though the user has scrolled further than 500px. Scrolling slower lessens this effect, hence why it works for you.

The solution to this is to make your code more robust by checking for a range of scrollTop values, for example using `>` instead of `=` in your example:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop >= 500) {
  console.log('You have scrolled down over 500px');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works but I get another problem. my if statement ist in a window.scroll function, and the event get started more than one time <br/>                                                                                                      $(window).scroll(function(){

    var abstandOben = $(window).scrollTop();
      var scrollvariable = 500;

      if(abstandOben >= scrollvariable){


        $("#nachladen").load("nachladen.php", {
    neueBeitragAnzahl: beitragAnzahl
   });

      }
  });

Comment: In that case you need to re-arrange you logic to work with this 'greater than' check. I'd suggest you start a new question about that. Make sure to include all relevant code, though.